# how to resize image for arcface?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, arcface

Hi I am trying to use arcface model with this code:

```
from deepface.basemodels.ArcFace import loadModel as loadArcFace
model = loadArcFace()
img = Image.open('face.jpg')
img = img.resize((112, 112), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = np.array(img)
model.predict(np.array(img))
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "ResNet34" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 112, 112, 3), found shape=(None, 112, 3)
```

But img.shape contains:

```
(112, 112, 3)
```

How can I reshape in order to use arcface?

Thanks

Comment: add batch axis. `np.expand_axis(img, axis=0)`

Comment: img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0), but thanks!